# CSS Styling for duplicate CSS

Tags: css

**EDIT DONE AT THE BOTTOM, PLEASE LOOK THERE FOR THE CURRENT QUESTION**

Okay, this is something I've tried to research as much as I can - but even though I'm a rather skilled Googler, I am at a loss for how to even properly describe this problem somehow concisely.

I'm building a forum. This forum allows for quoting, which is of course done through a styled quote box. The issue I've ran into is not that the quoting itself doesn't work, but the issue arises when several of these quotes intertwine. Basically, if I'm quoting a quote.

Is there a way to through CSS alter the behaviour of the style if it contains more than one? Or will I have to somehow programmatically disallow for multiple quotes? Should be some workaround, I mean heck - vBulletin and phpBB got it to work, heh!

I've taken a print to display the issue at hand. Below you'll also find my CSS styling for the quote box. Sadly I can't display it here as I don't have the reputation to do so, but I'll give you a link to it.

[image: My forum]

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgHAg.png)

For clarification, the "StackOverflow is awesome" should fall into the first quote box, and within that, "It truely is." would be the second quote.

CSS styling for quote boxes:

```
p.quote::first-line {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.67);
}

p.quote {
      background: #d4d4d4;
      border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
      margin: 1.5em 10px;
      padding: 0.5em 10px;
      quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
      font-size: 15px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, using Blockquotes as suggested seems like a good solution. The issue I run into with those however, is that the ::first-line argument no longer seems to respond after being executed once.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yLZf3/

Comment: It be easiest to use a direct child selector like so: `parent > p.quote::first-line { ... } parent > p.quote { ... }`

Comment: Would you elaborate? p.quote is a class created solely for these quote-blocks. In the case they are nested, it would make them their own parents.

Comment: From the looks of the image they *are* nested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the `<blockquote>` tag (*quoting* from the [MDN HTML element <blockquote> reference pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote)):

```
<blockquote cite="http://developer.mozilla.org">
  <p>This is a quotation taken from the Mozilla Developer Center.</p>
</blockquote>
```

And just style it accordingly. This has the advantage that adds the proper semantics to your page and using it may save you some trouble, [heres an (ugly) example](http://jsfiddle.net/nkZKf/1/):

**HTML**:

```
<blockquote cite="http://developer.mozilla.org">
    <p>This is a quotation taken from the Mozilla Developer Center.</p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>This is another quote</p>
            <blockquote>
                <p>This is another quote</p>
            </blockquote>
    </blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

**CSS**:

```
blockquote {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

blockquote p {
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Using a blockquote seems like a solid idea. I looked into this and now thinking back, I don't understand why I didn't go for it. I assume I had some kind of reason, heh!

Any idea of how to make it keep separating the first line though?
http://jsfiddle.net/yLZf3/ displays the issue I'm referring to with the user wrote: part.

Comment: I would have suggested a `<div>` and `<span>` only solution some days ago, but I read more on semantics so I thought this would have better implications, I hope this helps you.

Comment: It did help a whole bunch! Will mark it as the accepted answer as soon as I get a grip on how to solve the ::first-line issue.

Comment: You may want to use the `nth-child` selector, and select the first p child.